# auto correct the values in the text box on blur

Tags: javascript, html

I have one HTML page where I am having 3 text or number boxes in it. And I have set a number range for each text boxes like for "Minimum Length" it is 6 - 255 and the Lowercase and uppercase will have 0 as minimum and value of the "Minimum Length" as the maximum.

Now my question is suppose I have set "Minimum Length", Lowercase, Uppercase to 60, the values are getting saved in the config file and able to read the same values from the same. then if I change the "Minimum Length" value to 9 then the values of Lowercase and Uppercase which are set to 60 should also get changed to 9 coz 9 is lesser than 60 and max value of Lowercase and uppercase is set to the value of "Minimum Length". For the I have written blurfunc1() so the if I change the value of "Minimum Length" and click on commit then the values of Lowercase and uppercase also should get changed. But that is not working as expected. Am I doing anything wrong in blurfunc1() ??

```js
var isValidMinLen=true;
var isValidLC=true;
var isValidUC=true;
function checkLength_minlen(elem) {

if (elem.value == ''){
    document.getElementById("msg1").innerHTML = 'Min 6 and Max 256';
    document.getElementById("msg1").style.color = 'black';
    document.getElementById("btn").disabled = true;
    isValidMinLen=false;
  }
else if (elem.value < 6) {
    document.getElementById("msg1").style.color = 'red';
    document.getElementById("msg1").innerHTML="Min value is 6";
    document.getElementById("btn").disabled = true;
    isValidMinLen=false;
  }
  else if (elem.value > 256) {
    document.getElementById("msg1").style.color = 'red';
    document.getElementById("msg1").innerHTML="Max value is 256";
    document.getElementById("btn").disabled = true;
    isValidMinLen=false;
  }
 else {
   document.getElementById("msg1").style.color = 'green';
   document.getElementById("msg1").innerHTML="Min 6 and Max 256";
   isValidMinLen=true;
   checkButtonValidation();
  }
}

function checkLength_lc(elem) {
if (elem.value == ''){
    document.getElementById("msg4").innerHTML = "Min 0 and Max "+document.getElementById("Minlen_text").value;
    document.getElementById("msg4").style.color = 'black';
    document.getElementById("btn").disabled = true;
    isValidUC=false;
  }
else if (elem.value < 0) {
    document.getElementById("msg4").style.color = 'red';
    document.getElementById("msg4").innerHTML="Min value is 0";
    document.getElementById("btn").disabled = true;
    isValidUC=false;
  }
  else if (elem.value > +document.getElementById("Minlen_text").value) {
    document.getElementById("msg4").style.color = 'red';
    document.getElementById("msg4").innerHTML="Max value is "+document.getElementById("Minlen_text").value;
    document.getElementById("btn").disabled = true;
    isValidUC=false;
  }
 else {
   document.getElementById("msg4").style.color = 'green';
   document.getElementById("msg4").innerHTML="Min 0 and Max "+document.getElementById("Minlen_text").value;
   isValidUC=true;
   checkButtonValidation();
  }
}

function checkLength_uc(elem) {
if (elem.value == ''){
    document.getElementById("msg5").innerHTML = "Min 0 and Max "+document.getElementById("Minlen_text").value;
    document.getElementById("msg5").style.color = 'black';
    document.getElementById("btn").disabled = true;
    isValidUC=false;
  }
else if (elem.value < 0) {
    document.getElementById("msg5").style.color = 'red';
    document.getElementById("msg5").innerHTML="Min value is 0";
    document.getElementById("btn").disabled = true;
    isValidUC=false;
  }
  else if (elem.value > +document.getElementById("Minlen_text").value) {
    document.getElementById("msg5").style.color = 'red';
    document.getElementById("msg5").innerHTML="Max value is "+document.getElementById("Minlen_text").value;
    document.getElementById("btn").disabled = true;
    isValidUC=false;
  }
 else {
   document.getElementById("msg5").style.color = 'green';
   document.getElementById("msg5").innerHTML="Min 0 and Max "+document.getElementById("Minlen_text").value;
   isValidUC=true;
   checkButtonValidation();
  }
}
function checkButtonValidation(){
if(isValidMinLen==false || isValidLC==false || isValidUC==false){
    document.getElementById("btn").disabled = true;
}else{
   document.getElementById("btn").disabled = false;
}
}

function focusfunc1() {
document.getElementById("msg1").innerHTML = 'Min 6 and Max 255';
}
function blurfunc1() {
document.getElementById("msg1").innerHTML = ' ';
if (document.getElementById("Minlen_text").value < 6) {
        document.getElementById("Minlen_text").value = 6;
        document.getElementById("btn").disabled = false;
        }
else if(document.getElementById("Minlen_text").value > 255) {
        document.getElementById("Minlen_text").value = 255;
        document.getElementById("btn").disabled = false;
        }
else if(document.getElementById("Minlen_text").value == ' ') {
        document.getElementById("btn").disabled = true;
        }
else if(document.getElementById("LC_text").value && document.getElementById("UC_text").value > +document.getElementById("Minlen_text").value) {
        document.getElementById("LC_text").value = +document.getElementById("Minlen_text").value;
        document.getElementById("UC_text").value = +document.getElementById("Minlen_text").value;
        }
}
function focusfunc4() {
document.getElementById("msg4").innerHTML = 'Min 0 and Max '+document.getElementById("Minlen_text").value;
}
function blurfunc4() {
document.getElementById("msg4").innerHTML = ' ';
if (document.getElementById("LC_text").value < 0) {
        document.getElementById("LC_text").value = 0;
        document.getElementById("btn").disabled = false;
        }
else if(document.getElementById("LC_text").value > +document.getElementById("Minlen_text").value) {
        document.getElementById("LC_text").value = +document.getElementById("Minlen_text").value;
        document.getElementById("btn").disabled = false;
        }
}
function focusfunc5() {
document.getElementById("msg5").innerHTML = 'Min 0 and Max '+document.getElementById("Minlen_text").value;
}
function blurfunc5() {
document.getElementById("msg5").innerHTML = ' ';
if (document.getElementById("UC_text").value < 0) {
        document.getElementById("UC_text").value = 0;
        document.getElementById("btn").disabled = false;
        }
else if(document.getElementById("UC_text").value > +document.getElementById("Minlen_text").value) {
        document.getElementById("UC_text").value = +document.getElementById("Minlen_text").value;
        document.getElementById("btn").disabled = false;
        }
}
```

```html
 <div id="Minlen">
 <label class="heading">Minimum Length</label>
 <input type="number" id="Minlen_text" value="60" onkeyup="checkLength_minlen(this)" onfocus="focusfunc1()" onblur="blurfunc1()" pattern="[0-9]" onkeypress="return !(event.charCode == 46)" step="1" /> <span class="heading1" id="msg1"></span>
</div>
<div id="lowercase">
<label class="heading">Lowercase</label>
<input type="number" id="LC_text" onkeyup="checkLength_lc(this)" onfocus="focusfunc4()" onblur="blurfunc4()" pattern="[0-9]" onkeypress="return !(event.charCode == 46)" step="1" /> <span class="heading1" id="msg4"></span>
</div>
<div id="uppercase">
<label class="heading">Uppercase</label>
<input type="number" id="UC_text" onkeyup="checkLength_uc(this)" onfocus="focusfunc5()" onblur="blurfunc5()" pattern="[0-9]" onkeypress="return !(event.charCode == 46)" step="1" /> <span class="heading1" id="msg5"></span>
</div>
<input type=submit class="commit" id="btn" value=Commit onclick="commit()">
```

Comment: for input fields you check the value, not the innerHtml.